# Battery charging up to 80%

Tags: 18.04, battery

I’m using Ubuntu 18.04, I want the battery to be charging up to 100%. What should I do?

Comment: Possibly related:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130929/my-laptop-battery-never-charges-to-100-and-it-stays-on-99

Comment: What's your laptop brand and model? Does it support charging treshhold?

Comment: Samsung N145 plus. it does support I presume

Comment: Check into bios: some laptops have charge thresholds you can set. Never charging above 80% or draining below 20% significantly benefits battery life.

Comment: I’m new to Ubuntu is, can you guide me How I can check into the bios.